# Reducing social media requests

Tags: facebook, performance, widget, httprequest

I got about 30 requests from the various social media widgets.
Is there a way to reduce the number of requests?

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_badge" g:plusone:size="small"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
```

http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js%23pubid=xa-5284e3896308a336

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a wordpress website?
If yes you can use an lazy load social buttons plugin to reduce requests, if not, you can dig in a plugin's code like these and check the code to do the same for your website.

Comment: No I do not use wordpress, they are visible on just 1 page, but I want that page to load as fast as possible.